# mongoexport / mongodump halts when dump reaches 101 records

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongoexport

I'm trying to dump a MongoDB collection from a **remote server** to a **local** JSON file.

First, I do some ssh port forwading to begin with:

`ssh -NL 12345:localhost:27017 $REMOTE_USERNAME@$REMOTE_HOST &`

Then, the export itself:

`mongoexport -h $MONGODB_URL -d $MONGODB_DBNAME -c $MONGODB_COLLECTION -o $BACKUP_FILE --pretty`

What I would normaly get is something like this:

```
2019-02-07T14:58:15.322-0400    writing bubeIO.requests to
2019-02-07T14:58:18.754-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  0/2773  (0.0%)
2019-02-07T14:58:21.754-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  10/2773  (0.3%)
2019-02-07T14:58:24.754-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  20/2773  (0.6%)
...
...
2019-02-07T14:59:00.754-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  2773/2773  (100.0%)
```

But, what what I'm getting is this:

```
2019-02-07T14:58:15.322-0400    writing bubeIO.requests to
2019-02-07T14:58:18.754-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  0/2773  (0.0%)
2019-02-07T14:58:21.754-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  0/2773  (0.0%)
2019-02-07T14:58:24.754-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  0/2773  (0.0%)
2019-02-07T14:58:27.753-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:58:30.753-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:58:33.754-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:58:36.753-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:58:39.753-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:58:42.753-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:58:45.754-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:58:48.753-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:58:51.753-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:58:54.754-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:58:57.753-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:59:00.594-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:59:00.594-0400    Failed: error writing data for collection `bubeIO.requests` to disk: error reading collection: read tcp [::1]:61276->[::1]:12345: use of closed network connection
```

As you can see, it goes from 0 to 101 real quick and then it doesn't go anywhere from there until timeout.

It worked nicely before for remote dumps and suddenly this starts to happen. **Local dumps work just fine**, so this could be a networking issue?

Can anyone give me a direction on how to solve this?

PS: mongod and mongoexport are both version 4.0.2

Comment: Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29568427/mongodump-fails-frequently-after-upgrade-from-2-6-to-3-0

Comment: Do you have the same version of MongoDB server and the `mongoexport` tool? What's the output of `mongod --version` and `mongoexport --version`?

Comment: Hi, Kevin. I just checked and they both seem to be on the same version: 
`mongod --version` -> db version v4.0.2 and 
`mongexport --version` -> mongoexport version: r4.0.2